# How to iterate through an array inside an array.map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to iterate an array inside another loop in my react app. I have a json file that contains data that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id":"0001",
        "photos":[
            "IMG_9239.JPG",
            "2019-01-07.jpg",
            "IMG_9261.JPG"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"0002",
        "photos":[
            "IMG_9239.JPG",
            "2019-01-07.jpg",
            "IMG_9261.JPG"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"0003",
        "photos":[
            "IMG_9239.JPG",
            "2019-01-07.jpg",
            "IMG_9261.JPG"
        ]
    }
]
```

And this is my react component:

```
const ListItems = ({data}) => {
    return (
        <div id="items-container">
            {data.map( item => (
                <p>{item.id}</p>
                //iterate the [photos] array in an img tag
                //<img src ="photo" />
            ))}
        </div>
    )

}
```

I am trying `{item.photos.map....}` but it seems like it's not a valid syntax. Can you please help?

Comment: Can you show the error?

Comment: Unexpected token, expected ","

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple JSX elements require a parent, or at least a psuedo-parent. Here, you can use a fragment `<>` as the parent of what gets returned from the `.map` callback, enclosing both the `<p>` and the `<img>`s:

```
const ListItems = ({data}) => {
    return (
        <div id="items-container">
            {data.map( item => (
                <>
                    <p>{item.id}</p>
                    {item.photos.map(({ src }) => <img src={src}></img>}
                </>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```